# Pass/Fail images in Tkinter

Tags: image, tkinter

I want to show two different images when pressing two different buttons The "Show Pass" button should show an image (at a new window) with green color and text "PASS" on it while the "Show Fail" should show an image with red color and text "FAIL". However even though during creation of slave window (for PASS/FAIL images) i perform a withdraw to hide it, when i run program they are shown both images and pressing of "Show Pass" or "Show Fail" buttons have not [image]any affect. It follows my code:

```
from tkinter import *

GUI_WIDTH = 500
GUI_HEIGHT = 350

resultShown = False

def showUUTResult(UUTresult, slave):
    global resultShown
    if (resultShown == 'True'):
        slave.withdraw()
    slave = Toplevel()
    slave.deiconify()
    slave.title("Res")
    canvas_width = 185
    canvas_height = 150
    canvas = Canvas(slave, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
    canvas.grid(row=5, column=5, sticky=N)
    if UUTresult == 'PASS':
        img = PhotoImage(file="C:\PythonPrograms\Pass.png")
        print('Result is PASS')
    elif UUTresult == 'FAIL':
        img = PhotoImage(file="C:\PythonPrograms\Fail.png")
        print('Result is FAIL')
    else:
        print('Unknown UUT Result Type!')
    canvas.create_image(10, 10, anchor=NW, image=img)
    canvas.image = img
    resultShown = 'True'

master = Tk()
gui_resolution = str(GUI_WIDTH)+'x'+str(GUI_HEIGHT)
master.geometry(gui_resolution)
master.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
master.title("PASS FAIL Trial")
slave = Toplevel()
slave.withdraw()

passTestButton = Button(master, text="Show Pass", command=showUUTResult('PASS', slave))
passTestButton.grid(column=1, row=0, pady=5, ipadx=12)
failTestButton = Button(master, text="Show Fail", command=showUUTResult('FAIL', slave))
failTestButton.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=5, ipadx=12)

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the lines that create the buttons and assign a command to them.

```
failTestButton = Button(master, text="Show Fail", command=showUUTResult('FAIL', slave))
```

What this is saying is create a button with the text "Show Fail" and set the command to the result of the function showUUTResult when passed some arguments. showUUTResult doesn't return anything so what happens is that the window opens straight away when your program runs, showing the image, but clicking on the button does nothing.

You can solve this with a simple addition

```
failTestButton = Button(master, text="Show Fail", command=lambda: showUUTResult('FAIL', slave))
```

`lambda` creates an anonymous function which is called when the button is pressed.

This should fix your problem.